# Concern ADO.net Command

Tags: sql, ado.net

I want execute the following command text(sql statement) which command I need to use?

```
command.CommandText="select Fname from table_name where Lname='abc'"
```

I need to use ExecutScalar or ExecuteReader command, could you please confirm.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What happens when you try one of them? Does it work? If not, what happens when you try the other one?

Comment: i am confusing with the answer,my scenario is i want display Lname based on Fname and display Lname in the label

Answer (score 2):

Either will work. It depends on the expected results.

If you are only returning a single value, `ExecuteScalar` would be preferred.

Otherwise, use `ExecuteReader` or fill a `DataTable`

Comment: i am confusing with the answer,my scenario is i want display Lname based on Fname and display Lname in the label